# Moderator Elections -- How many moderators can the site have?

Tags: discussion, election

How many moderators can the site have?

How many moderators can an individual vote for?

Answer (score 6):

As posted in the other answer, we have three open moderator slots and each user gets to note their top three choices.

This might seem as if we're losing a moderator, since we currently have four, but, of the four, only one is active on a daily basis, with the other three either entirely inactive, or only on the site very occasionally.

I do want to add that there's actually no set number to how many mods a site may have.  Most have three, at least initially.

SE decides if you need more than that and will [add positions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/284336) (with a new election), usually based on the site's traffic and question numbers.

> The community team periodically looks at the work load on graduated sites and will reach out to the moderation team if it looks like more help might be needed. Broadly, it's up to the moderation teams to indicate whether they need additional hands, and how many sets of hands would be ideal.

For example, Stack Overflow has [18 moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) because they have extremely high traffic and other sites have various other amounts, including

- 9 [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- 8 [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- 6 [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- 5 [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

Occasionally, additional moderators will need to be added to replace (or augment) moderators who are no longer as active on the site, though I think once a site graduates, it's rare for a moderator to lose their position.

Comment: Good information here. Just one more note of clarification: initially, ELL had three moderators; a fourth was appointed only after one of the three had requested to be relieved of their duties. That moderator kept the diamond tag, but it was mostly a mod team of three from that point forward.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @J.R. :)

Comment: Also worth noting that of the 8 technically-recognized EL&U mods, only 3 (sometimes 4) actively engage in moderation. Of the other 4, one is an "honorary moderatorship" bestowed on a valuable contributor to the community, and the other 3 haven't been seen in ages. One's profile still urges you to support the Area51 proposal for ELL :)

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for that! It's always good to know how many mods are actually active on a site.

Comment: Huh, for its size I would have guessed SO had far more moderators than that.

Answer (score 4):

> How many moderators can the site have?
>
> **moderator positions available: 3**
>
> How many moderators can an individual vote for?
>
> **Three, with order of preference.**

Very useful links: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) and [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)

Comment: To clarify part of this - this particular election is being run for 3 positions, but we can support elections to fill in anywhere from 1-5. Regardless of the number of open positions, though, the maximum number of names any user may assign their vote for is always 3.